# Diode OR with more than two sources

Tags: power-supply, diodes, multiplexer, rtc

[image: Multi diode]

Is this type of system a good idea? I tried multiplexing two coin cells, one USB and one booster using four Schottky diodes (CUS10S30.) Schematic is given below.

The RTC does not work properly in this scenario (interrupts are not occurring, clock battery supplies power to the MCU.)

[image: schematic]
It works fine if I use two separate batteries like below:

[image: working_schematic]

Is the design flawed? I want to run the RTC if any one of the batteries is present.

Comment: It's not clear how the PCF is supplied… it only has one power supply yet you enter with two power lines

Comment: Thanks, Fixed it in the schematic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, be careful of sneak currents… when you power one chip and the other ones are not there is a chance to inadvertently supply other parts with some leakage or maybe some milliamps of current. The RTC ports are all open drain so it shouldn't be a problem (fig. 22 in the datasheet shows the internal paths, mostly clamps to ground and vdd). It sometimes happens that a whole subsection is parasitically powered by a single GPIO!

If you are seeing the clock battery on the MCU side there is probably some sneak path you haven't found yet. At least INT, SDA and SCL should not let power thru: they have no clamp to VDD and at least INT is *explicitly* marked as open drain. SDA and SCL *should* be open drain but in some peripherals (I doubt in a PCF part) there could be edge accelerators that could pass something through.

The simplest way would be to pull out the MCU and see on which pin of the RTC you see the unwanted supply. Otherwise look with a millivolt-capable DMM and try to follow the supply upstream to the relevant pin (it could take *a lot* of time).

Asking NXP for ideas is an option too!

By the way there are RTCs with a dedicated backup battery port (like the horribly expensive yet precise Maxim parts), you could consider them.

Comment: Pulling out the MCU and probing the RTC sounds like a good point to start. Thank you very much!
And also thanks for the idea of asking NXP. Will definitely ask them.

Answer (score 2):

Did you mean Schottky diode?

Whenever you load a coin cell, known to have high series resistance with a dynamic load , you get load regulated voltage errors on the source.

Putting a bigger coin cell in parallel with a smaller one causes it to supply most of the current with no sharing as expected.

Putting a voltage booster cause more current demand on the source, which results in more load regulated source voltage error or noise with a dynamic pulsed load.

Thus the boost regulator could be expected to interfere with the RTC if if has a low tolerance for supply noise or perhaps dropouts below Vdd min in pulses.

If you confirm thatvis what happened, then yes it is a bad design.  Bulk caps can even out rhe voltage ripple but under-powering a device with dynamic load regulated noise without analysis is likely to have a poor outcome.

Measuring the battery level and reviewing the RTC supply specs and App notes is your next step. Using a low ESR bulk may be a solution or a better backup power source.

Comment: Thank you! I never suspected that dynamic load can be an issue. Can you please suggest me a rough size for the supercap ?